Set default headphone output level on boot
I have a headless Raspberry Pi running Debian that's used as an audio player. I'd like to boost the output of the headphone device at boot time.
I've found the command amixer --card 1 sset 'PCM',0 0 will set the output to 0dB, but where do I put this in the boot sequence so it's part of the default configuration?
Is there a better way to configure the device?
The web is full of deprecated methods such as modifying now non-existent /etc config files.
